# Why do my .bat files print their contents?

Tags: batch-file

When I save an `install.bat` with `echo hi` as its sole content, it prints:

```
C:\ > install.bat
C:\ > echo hi
hi
```

I just want `hi`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start the bat file with the line

```
@echo off
```

The `@` supresses displaying that line, and the `echo off` turns off displaying the rest of the lines.

Answer (score 4):

Either use `@echo hi` or start the batch file with `@echo off`.